# std::lower_bound on std::vector with reverse iterators yields a wrong result

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Recently I have came across a need to count elements that are outside of a given interval.

For example, if I have a sorted vector { 10, 20, 30 } and another sorted vector { 15, 25 }, whose boundaries define the interval. I want to count '10' and '30' (only 20 is inside the range). For this I use std::vector and std::lower_bound, once forward-scanning the vector, and once backward-scanning.

The code looks as following:

```
    int t[] = { 15, 25 };
int c[] = { 10, 20, 30 };

std::vector<int> tt(t, t + 2);
std::vector<int> cc(c, c + 3);

auto lower = std::lower_bound(cc.begin(), cc.end(), tt.front(), [](int a, int b){ return a < b; });
auto upper = std::lower_bound(cc.rbegin(), cc.rend(), tt.back(), [](int a, int b){ return a > b; });

size_t beforeCount = lower - cc.begin();
size_t afterCount = upper - cc.rbegin();
```

I expect both 'lower' and 'upper' to point to the same element: 20.

I've spent some time on this, does anyone see a problem here?
I really want to use STL for that.

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Are you reinventing [equal_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/)? The code looks legit. Both `*lower` and `*upper` are 20 and `beforeCount` and `afterCount` are 1. What makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: What is your problem ? What is your current output and what is your expected output ?

Comment: "I expect both 'lower' and 'upper' to point to the same element: 20." --- They do.

Comment: why are you using STL for that? Just write a simple loop..

Comment: @nwp: thank you, indeed it looks like I can achieve the same with equal_range, but still I'll have to call it twice, since my range is described by more than one value. I see no added value by using equal_range here, am I missing anything perhaps?

Comment: @quantdev: sorry for not being clear, lower points to the expected element (20), but upper points to the last one (30). I expect 20 and 20.

Comment: @n.m.: 20 and 30 here respectively

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky: I prefer to use existing binary search routine than write one of my own

Comment: [ideone](http://ideone.com/bHIRct) gives the result you expect. Please give an example that shows the "wrong" output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are confused between the difference of an iterator, and the value pointed-to by an iterator.

Your program is doing exactly what you think, see it [here](http://ideone.com/m7LtQs).

`beforeCount` and `afterCount` are both equal to 1. They are iterators, not the value of any of your vector element, they are merely pointer to values in your vector.

To print the corresponding elements, simply do :

```
std::cout << cc[beforeCount] << std::endl;
std::cout << cc[afterCount] << std::endl;
```

**Output:**

20

20

**Note:**

You can initialize your vector without the intermediate arrays:

```
std::vector<int> tt { 15, 25 };
std::vector<int> cc  { 10, 20, 30 } ;
```

Comment: quantdev, thank you for your answer.

I don't think I'm confusing iterators and values pointed to by the iterators.

I see that beforeCount and afterCount (magically, for me) both equal 1. However I don't understand why "upper" doesn't point to 20, but to 30. I expect it to point to 20.


Btw, notice that "std::cout << cc[afterCount] << std::endl;" works here only because the iterator points to the 2nd value out of 3. I guess you meant cc[cc.size() - afterCount - 1]?

Comment: Btw, I am using VS2012 and still can't initialize the vector the way you propose (already tried that). Perhaps you can know why? VS2012 should implement full C++11 spec

Comment: I think my mistake was looking at 'upper' in the debugger, which points to value '30'. *upper yields 20. Not quite understandable to me why, perhaps its the debugger that confuses me?

Comment: I'm not sure at what you're looking in the debugger, but for me (unix) it givrs the correct result.

Comment: MSVC2012 gives a wrong result apparently. Anyway now I see the code works fine. Thank you

Comment: "which points to value '30'. *upper yields 20. Not quite understandable to me why". That's because reverse iterators are not implemented like you expect they would. If you examine `cc.rbegin()` you will see it "points to" garbage, not to the last element. In fact it points to the same place `cc.end()` does. It has to be that way, otherwise you cannot implement `rend()`. Everything else follows.

Answer (score 0):

I find it sometimes difficult to reason about reverse-iterators. You can avoid using them as follows:

```
auto first = std::lower_bound(cc.begin(), cc.end(), tt.front());
auto second = std::upper_bound(first, cc.end(), tt.back());

size_t beforeCount = first - cc.begin();
size_t afterCount = cc.end() - second;
```

This is very similar to `equal_range`, so in fact we can rewrite it as follows (though it may be troublesome on MSVC which had non-standard implementation w.r.t. heterogeneous comparators in the past):

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Pr;
struct Cmp {
    bool operator()(int x, const Pr &y) { return x < y.first; }
    bool operator()(const Pr &x, int y) { return x.second < y; }
};
auto pr = std::equal_range(cc.begin(), cc.end(), Pr(15, 25), Cmp());

size_t beforeCount = pr.first - cc.begin();
size_t afterCount = cc.end() - pr.second;
```